# Diferenças entre Log4J e SLF4J

Tags: java, log, log4j

Quais as `vantagens` e `desvantagens` de cada um? Eles podem ser `usados simultaneamente` no mesmo projeto?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A vantagem do [`SLF4J`](http://www.slf4j.org/) é que se trata de uma abstração de muitos dos frameworks de log existentes, permitindo a criação de programa, frameworks e bibliotecas independente da implementação concreta de log a ser utilizada.

Isso é importante, por exemplo, porque a mesma aplicação pode ser distribuída (*deploy*) em diferentes servidores de aplicação que usam mecanismos de log diferentes. Além disso, há um problema sério quando diferentes bibliotecas ou classes utilizadas num mesmo projeto utilizam mecanismos de log diferentes. Imagine usar um framework MVC que usa o `java.util.logging`, um framework de persistência que usa o `Apache Commons Logging` e outro framework de relatórios que usa o Log4j. A API de cada um desses é diferente e podem surgir conflitos de classes e configuração.

O `SLF4J` consegue trabalhar em conjunto com o `Log4j` sem nenhuma dificuldade, além de também poder usar outras implementações.

Então, se todos os componentes de um programa usam a mesma abstração (`SLF4J`, no caso), então o desenvolvedor ou o responsável pelo ambiente final fica livre para usar a biblioteca de sua escolha, sem comprometer o desenvolvimento por causa de um componente de terceiros.

O único contexto que consigo ver onde seria vantajoso usar somente o Log4j, seria no caso de um projeto sem dependências externas, pois não haveria razão para abstrair o mecanismo de log.